# Bug In WMD Markdown Editor

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, editor

To make a line break, you have to end a sentence with two spaces.
To make a paragraph, you create a whole line between two blocks to text.

But when you create a line break, it doesn't end the formatting from the previous line like when you create a new paragraph.

#### Edit

Also, it seems that some examples of this bug (such as the first example which shows italics) only appear within the WMD preview and doesn't show up on the actual post itself.

### Examples

Here's a method with an underscore: test_method
Here's another method with an underscore: foo_bar

[This only breaks in WMD preview]

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

Here's a method with an underscore: test_method

Here's another method with an underscore: foo_bar

---

Heres another **example

Woah, I'm a new** line!

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

Heres another **example

Woah, I'm a new** line!

---

Here's some `code

foo = bar`

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

Here's some `code

foo = bar`

---

A method/function with underscores instead of spaces: i_am_a_test_method

[This only breaks in WMD preview]

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this is by design and part of the markdown spec.

You can try it at the [babelmark markdown testbed](http://babelmark.bobtfish.net/) if you like.

Comment: It seems the only Markdown implementations that catch this problem are BlueCloth and Maruku.. of course the Ruby implementations catch it =p /rubyfanboy

Comment: Also, that's pretty lame that markdown would do that by default.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood - You are correct. Text formatting will end (reset) with the start of a new paragraph. But a line break does not start a new paragraph so the formatting continues. This is consistent with any editor I can recall.

Comment: Yes, but on stack overflow people often type in code and it is pretty standard to use underscores in place of spaces in method/function names. So it could easily confuse a method/function name with markdown formatting.

Comment: There, I edited it. See the last example, i_am_a_test_method. That only gets formatted within the WMD preview pane but displays correctly in the actual post. That's definitely a bug.

Comment: I thought the problem was "...But when you create a line break, it doesn't end the formatting." Now I'm not sure which "bug" you are reporting. Maybe I misread it.

Comment: It started as that as the bug, but then I found out that the way WMD's preview renders it and the way the server renders it are different. =p

Answer (score 1):

The real bug here – the inconsistency between the preview and the server-rendered version – was fixed a long time ago.